# Cannot read from a binary file using fscanf

Tags: c, csv

I am writing a program that is supposed to serialize/deserialize CSV to BIN/BIN to CSV in C.
Currently, I'm struggling with the deserialization for the third day and since I tried everything I could, I decided to ask here.
The way I'm doing the serialization is as follows:

```
void serialize(FILE* input_file,FILE* output_file)
{
    char buffer[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
    struct order
    {
        char* row_id;
        char* order_id;
        char* order_date;
        char* customer_id;
        char* city;
        char* state;
        char* postal_code;
        char* region;
        char* product_id;
        char* category;
        char* sub_category;
        char* price;
    } ;

    struct order order_buffer = {0};

    fgets(buffer,MAX_LINE_LENGTH, input_file);
    
    while(fgets(buffer, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, input_file) != NULL)
    {
        char* token = NULL;

        token = strtok(buffer, ",");
        order_buffer.row_id = token;

        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        order_buffer.order_id = token;

        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        order_buffer.order_date = token;

        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        order_buffer.customer_id = token;

        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        order_buffer.city = token;

        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        order_buffer.state = token;

        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        order_buffer.postal_code = token;

        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        order_buffer.region = token;

        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        order_buffer.product_id = token;

        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        order_buffer.category = token;

        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        order_buffer.sub_category = token;

        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        order_buffer.price = token;

        fwrite(&order_buffer, sizeof(order_buffer), 1, output_file);
    }
}
```

This code takes the CSV file line by line and tokenizes it on the comma.
After that it stores it into a struct (all char arrays on this iteration though some of them are ints)

All's good up until here, I was able to serialize the CSV file and reduce its size from 1.2 mb to about 470 kb.

However, I cannot deserialize it.
I tried several different methods, and at the end I decided fscanf would be best, here's the code:

```
void deserialize(FILE* input_file, FILE* output_file)
{
    char buffer[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
    struct order
    {
        char* row_id;
        char* order_id;
        char* order_date;
        char* customer_id;
        char* city;
        char* state;
        char* postal_code;
        char* region;
        char* product_id;
        char* category;
        char* sub_category;
        char* price;
    } ;

    struct order order_buffer = {0};
    char* line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];

    fscanf(input_file, "%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s",
           order_buffer.row_id,
           order_buffer.order_id,
           order_buffer.order_date,
           order_buffer.customer_id,
           order_buffer.city,
           order_buffer.state,
           order_buffer.postal_code,
           order_buffer.region,
           order_buffer.product_id,
           order_buffer.category,
           order_buffer.sub_category,
           order_buffer.price);

    printf("%s", order_buffer.order_id);


    printf("%s", order_buffer.row_id);
}
```

The function can create a new csv file, but doesn't write anything into it, and doesn't assign any values to the struct.
I'm guessing it's got something to do with the char arrays being uninitialized, but beyond that I'm completely lost.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "I decided fscanf would be best" -- Wrong.  Please explain the expected outcome of format `"%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s"` using some example input. I guess you will find the problem while describing that.

Comment: The `scanf` family of functions are *text* based. But that is a moot point since you save data that can't be saved. `fwrite(&order_buffer, sizeof(order_buffer), 1, output_file);` will write the *pointers* not the strings they are pointing to. And pointers are local to the currently running process. You can't read pointers from any other process, not even if its started by the same program.

Comment: it is example sales data, it has 12 columns, here's an example line:  
`1,"CA-2016-152156",11/8/2016,"CG-12520","Henderson","Kentucky",42420,"South","FUR-BO-10001798","Furniture","Bookcases",261.96`
Some of the fields are not strings, but for serialization it didn't matter (I tried assigning ints and a float at the end but the result is the same)
The format is like that since I think this is what it has it saved as (considering tokenization doesn't take the delimiter but replaces it)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude how do you suggest I save the data then?

Comment: I would recommend that you don't do any conversion at all. Why can't you use the original CSV file? What is your actual and underlying problem you try to solve with the binary file? What is your assignment or exercise? Right now this is very much an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the point of the exercise is to serialize the  csv data into a binary format. The main idea behind it is that the generated bin file should be much smaller than the original csv, and then the program should be able to de-serialize a file it's generated back into csv.

Comment: As for the serialization itself, just like parsing CSV it's actually much harder than it seems at a first glance. If you want to handle variable-length data like strings, you need to figure out a way to store it that can be easily deserialised later. You might have to take into account things like alignment, byte-ordering and endianness of multi-byte values, offests and padding, and many more issues. And the format needs to be very formally specified and well-documented (*before* you start to write any code!).

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include the full and complete assignment, especially its requirements and limitations? Please copy-paste it as text.

Comment: Text doesn't automatically get smaller just because you store it in a binary file. A string of X characters will still be a string of X characters, doesn't matter if it's in a binary file or in a text file.  And if you prefix all strings with a fixed-size `uint32_t` value to say how long each string is, then your binary file will likely be *larger* than the original source file. I come back to my previous recommendation: Unless it's an actual hard *requirement* of the assignment to have a binary file, just don't do it. If it's for school, then please talk to your teacher about the assignment.

Comment: If space is your primary concern, you're probably much better off **compressing** the original CSV (e.g. as a [zip](https://libzip.org/)).

Answer (score 0):

You are initialising an order structure with **pointers** to some text string data....

```cpp
    struct order
    {
        char* row_id;
        char* order_id;
        char* order_date;
        char* customer_id;
        char* city;
        char* state;
        char* postal_code;
        char* region;
        char* product_id;
        char* category;
        char* sub_category;
        char* price;
    };
```

You are then writing the **pointers** to the disk. You are not writing the text strings that they point to.

```cpp
    fwrite(&order_buffer, sizeof(order_buffer), 1, output_file);
```

If you are going to parse the CSV data into something meaningful, i.e. parse the text string for `state` into say, an enum:

```cpp
    enum State {
       NSW,
       Victoria, 
       Tasmania, 
       Queensland,
    };

    State text_to_state(const char* text) {
       if(!strcmp(text, "NSW")) return NSW;
       if(!strcmp(text, "Tasmania")) return Tasmania;
       /* snip */

       // bad input
       abort(); 
    }
    
    struct order
    {
        State state;
    };
```

Then that should be fine to throw at fwrite/fread with no additional work.

If things like 'product_id' nicely map to say an integer, use an integer in the struct!

```cpp
    int text_to_integer(const char* text) {
       return atoi(text)
    }
    
    struct order
    {
        State state;
        int product_id;
    };
```

If you need an actual text string as part of the data structure, you'll either need to use a fixed sized char array, or be cleverer (e.g. fwrite the string size, then fwrite the actual string data).

```cpp
    struct order
    {
        State state;
        int product_id;
        char customer_name[64];
    };
```

For things like 'price', either use a decimal type, or store in multiples of pence/cents, and use an integer.

```cpp
    while(fgets(buffer, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, input_file) != NULL)
    {
        char* token = NULL;

        /* snip */

        token = strtok(buffer, ",");
        order_buffer.state = text_to_state(token);

        /* snip */

        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        order_buffer.product_id = text_to_integer(token);

        /* snip */

        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        strcpy(order_buffer.customer_name, token);

        /* snip */

        // then, and only then, will a binary file make sense. 
        fwrite(&order_buffer, sizeof(order_buffer), 1, output_file);
    }
```

Then when you read it back in, all of the data you expect will be there, e.g.

```cpp
        // then, and only then, will a binary file make sense. 
        fread(&order_buffer, sizeof(order_buffer), 1, output_file);
```

If however you want to keep everything as text strings, just use the original CSV text file as storage....

Comment: would it  be prudent if I wrote the token to the new file instead of the struct element?

Comment: You could write individual values to the file, however writing a single struct in one go is usually the way people tend to go.

Answer (score 0):

There were two logic error.

```c
struct order
{
    char* row_id;
    char* order_id;
    char* order_date;
    char* customer_id;
    char* city;
    char* state;
    char* postal_code;
    char* region;
    char* product_id;
    char* category;
    char* sub_category;
    char* price;
};
```

You output with `fwrite(&order_buffer, sizeof(order_buffer), 1, output_file);`.

It will only write the `char *` pointers to file, instead of the memory they point to.
It won't be what you want.

Another error:

```c
fscanf(input_file, "%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s",...);
```

A `%s` will stop matching until a `' '`, `'\t'` or `'\n'`.

You write the content with `fwrite()`, which won't add white-space character.

Then the first `%s` will matchs the whole string until `EOF` when `fscanf()` called.

Another potential error is the byte alignment if mixing `fwrite()` and `fscanf()`.

```c
struct order {
    char *str_1; // 8 bytes on 64bit os
    int8_t a; // 8 bytes too.
};
```

---

`fread()` usually be used together with `fwrite()`.
And `fscanf()` is used together with `fprintf()`.

You'd better add spaces or width in `fprintf()` if you use `fscanf()`.

For example:

```c
fprintf (outfile, "%s %s", hello, world);
fscanf (infile, "%s %s", &hello, &world);
//OR
fprintf (outfile, "%10s%8s", hello, world);
fscanf (infile, "%10s%8s", &hello, &world);
```